# cancel or reset inherited css styles

Tags: css

let's say I have a button which has the following css style applied to it:

```
.my_button
{
    height: 30px;
}
```

Now let's say on some pages in my application, I don't want my button to have a height of 30px (Neither do I want to give it a new height), I want it to have its default height set by jquery ui. How can I cancel/reset that css that is applied to my button?

Thank you

Comment: To answer this definitively we would need to know how jquery-ui is setting the height.  Does it have a css rule which this one is overwriting?

Comment: can't you just remove the class that is overriding your default height?

Answer (score 2):

To reset a CSS property, set it to the default value.

For `height`, the default value is `auto`.

To get the default for any style, open `about:blank` and run the following in your JS console:

```
getComputedStyle(document.createElement('span')).PROPERTY
```

Where `PROPERTY` is the one you want. `height`, `width`, `background-color`, whatever you want to find the default for.

Comment: Same. In fact, I'll add a script to my answer you can use to find any default style.

Comment: I get empty string every time, when I use that function in Chrome Console

Comment: Strange, I'm getting the right results in all browsers I have to test with... Actually, try `getComputedStyle(document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('span'))).PROPERTY`.

Comment: @Kolink Some CSS properties can be accessed by name, but many others can only be retrieved through `.getPropertyValue`. For cross-browser compability, I recommend to have a look at the code and notes in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9432023/938089), or simply use jQuery to retrieve the default values (since jQuery has already been loaded). Also, the default CSS property value of a `<span>` element is not necessarily equal to the button element without `my_button` class.

Comment: Remember that if the property has a "-" in the name you must use square bracket notation: `getComputedStyle(document.createElement('span'))["SOME-PROPERTY"]`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the .my_button class , like this:

```
$('#ID_of_thebutton').removeClass('my_button')
```