# Download element in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, download

I'm trying to download all content inside `div` tag using javascript

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="invoice">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        
            <p>My Name</p>
            <p>My Email</p>
            <p>My Address</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h6>Number</h6>
            <br />
            <p>2021</p>
            <br />
            <h6>Another Number</h6>
            <br />
            <p>2021</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h6>Date</h6>
            <br />
            <p>9/14/2021</p>
            <br />
            <h6>Terms</h6>
            <br />
            <p>30</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <table class="table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>th1</th>
                <th>th2</th>
                <th>th3</th>
                <th>th4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>
                 content1
               </td>
               <td>
                   content2
               </td>
               <td>
                   content3
               </td>
               <td>
                   content4
               </td>
               
           </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
 
</div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
    function downloadMyElement() {
   var MyElement=document.getElementById('invoice').innerHTML;
        var filename = "MyElement.html";
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(MyElement));
        element.setAttribute('download', filename);
        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
        document.body.removeChild(element);

    }
```

the result:

[image]

the table didn't display and not the same design I think my code in javascript didn't read the tags.

How can I get the same design of my markup?

Comment: You forgot to include your stylesheet.

Comment: To offer the browser to obtain the HTML text of your element, albeit without suggesting the filename or forcing the download action, the following alone will do: `location = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([ document.getElementById('invoice').innerHTML ], "text/html"))`

Comment: @Quentin I have stylesheet in folder and call it in the html file. Do you have any source for how to add it to javascript, please?

Comment: @sameehshadid — Presumably the stylesheet is in the `<head>` so it isn't inside the `innerHTML` of the `div`…

Comment: @Quentin I have stylsheet in my project and when I display the page worked well with design but when download it shown like the picture above.

Comment: @sameehshadid — Yes, you said that and I explained why that's the case in my previous comment.

Comment: @Quentin I have it like this `<head><link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>`

Comment: Exactly. So it won't be inside `document.getElementById('invoice').innerHTML`, will it?

Comment: @Quentin no it won't be.

Answer (score 1):

The correct method is [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), not `innerHtml` (names in JavaScript are *case-sensitive*):

```
var MyElement = document.getElementById('invoice').innerHTML;
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fp2sybc/))

If you want to include the parent `div` element named "invoice", you should use [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).

For including the styles you'll have to play around with [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Chech [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9432023/3990896).

Comment: Thanks for correcting me but same issue, in the output didn't divide the `div` into columns and table didn't show.

Comment: See my edit for including the parent div.

Comment: I tried this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/5fp2sybc/) now but gave the same thing. I think the problem that the javascript doesn't read the stylsheet. Do you have any idea for how to add the stylesheet in javascript?\

Comment: Added to the answer some links. Check them out.

Comment: still the same. is there anyway to get the tags inside the `div` with their styles?
Like if I have `<div><button></button></div>` how can I get the button to appear in the downloaded file